# wrong recipient when replying to mail fetched via POP3

Tags: email, gmail, pop3, reply

In Gmail web client's `Settings -> Accounts and Import`, I've

1. added `myothermail@example.com` in `Check mail from other accounts:` to pull data via POP; incoming mail gets labeled
2. added `myothermail@example.com` in `Send mail as:` to be able to send mail as myothermail@example.com

When a third party sends mail to myothermail@example.com and I try to reply to it in Gmail, it sets myothermail@example.com as recipient instead of said 3rd party who sent the mail.

How to make sure `Reply` function populates `To` field with correct addressee? I'd expect to be able to send reply *from* myothermail@example.com *to* 3rd party.

Comment: We have no idea what App you are using or what you tried with the App. In Outlook, POP3, I set the Reply Account in Advanced POP Account settings. Works.

Comment: @John question is tagged with `gmail` label. I'll edit to make it more explicit.

Comment: There may be a separate setting to set the default reply account. This is done to prevent relaying, but I am not familiar with Gmail POP.

Comment: Are you sure that this message is not spam? Some spammers add a false reply-to header in the email.

Comment: Did you check the "Alias" option when adding the address through "Send mail as"?

Comment: @harrymc sent from my own mail for testing purposes.

Comment: @u1686_grawity tried both alias and non-alias options -- both behave the same.

Comment: I fail to understand : The said 3rd party is yourself? Sent from which account?

Comment: @harrymc from not _the_ gmail, nor `myothermail@example.com`; hence "3rd" in the wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the account I sent the test email from had also been added as `Send mail as` alias causing this anomaly. Meaning this won't be an issue replying to true external addresses.